# Expected value of a generalized exponential distribution

Tags: self-study, expected-value, exponential-distribution

(This is taken from a class.) I was given a generalized exponential distribution: 
$f(x) = \alpha/\beta\, e^{-x/\beta}+c$. As follows and calculate the expected value of the distribution:

\begin{eqnarray}
f(t) &=& \color{red}{\alpha}\frac{_1}{^\beta}e^{-\frac{t}{\beta}}+\color{red}{C}\\
 &=& (3.34\times 10^{-1})\cdot(2.172\times 10^{-3})\cdot \,e^{-2.172\times 10^{-3}\,t}\,+\:\text{(negligible)}\\
\mathbb{E}[t]&\approx& 153.83 \text{ seconds}
\end{eqnarray}

But what confused me is the way he calculate the expected value. Here's what he do in the python code:

```python
# define fit function
def fitFunc_gen(t, a, b, c):
    return a*(b)*numpy.exp(-b*t)+c

# find fit parameters of a,b,c
fitParams_gen, fitCov_gen = curve_fit(fitFunc_gen, division[0:len(division)-1], 
                                      count, p0=[0, 3e-4, 0])

#expect value
ev = (1/fitParams_gen[1])*fitParams_gen[0]+fitParams_gen[1]
# ev= 153.8330951411821
```

As can be seen from the code, the formula he used for expected value is: $E(X) = \alpha\times\beta + 1/\beta$. However I did the calculation myself:

\begin{eqnarray}
E(X) &=& \int_{-\infty}^\infty x f(x) dx\\
&&\hspace{2.5cm}\:\downarrow\:c\approx 0\\
E(X) &=& \int_{-\infty}^\infty x  \frac{\alpha}{\beta}\,e^{-\frac{x}{\beta}} dx\\
&=&\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\int_{0}^\infty x \,e^{-\frac{x}{\beta}} dx\\
&=&-\alpha\int_{0}^\infty x\,(-\frac{1}{\beta}) \,e^{-\frac{x}{\beta}} dx\\
&=&-\alpha\int_{0}^\infty x\, de^{-\frac{x}{\beta}}\\
&=&-\alpha \left(
xe^{-\frac{x}{\beta}}|_{0}^\infty  -
\int_{0}^\infty e^{-\frac{x}{\beta}}dx \right)\\
&=&-\alpha\left(0+
\beta\int_{0}^\infty (-\frac{1}{\beta})e^{-\frac{x}{\beta}}dx\right)\\
&=&-\alpha\beta\int_{0}^\infty (-\frac{1}{\beta})e^{-\frac{x}{\beta}}dx\\
&=&-\alpha\beta e^{-\frac{x}{\beta}}|_{0}^\infty=\alpha\beta
\end{eqnarray}

I think it should be $E(X)=\alpha\times\beta$.

Can anyone correct me?

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: https://discourse-cdn.global.ssl.fastly.net/udacity/uploads/default/original/3X/b/3/b3c154ca0cd23a0400f6ead5a5b9ec0791e81108.png  and  https://discourse-cdn.global.ssl.fastly.net/udacity/uploads/default/original/3X/b/c/bcc62771bff34ed9d29cab1a7a3cf422bb05e550.jpg,  I want to add these two fig

Answer (score 1):

The whole thing is problematic, because you don't specify the support of the claimed probability density.  If $X$ is a random variable with density $$f_X(x) = \frac{\alpha}{\beta}e^{-x/\beta} + c,$$ then there is necessarily some relationship between the parameters $\alpha, \beta, c$ and the subset $x \in \Omega \subseteq \mathbb R$ for which $f(x) > 0$ and $$\int_{x \in \Omega} f_X(x) \, dx = 0.$$  Note, for instance, that if $c \ne 0$ and $\Omega$ comprises a single continuous interval, the support is necessarily bounded below and above.  If we require $\Omega = (0, \infty)$, then this forces $c = 0$.  If $c = 0$, then again on this same interval, we would obtain $$\int_{x=0}^\infty f_X(x) \, dx = \alpha = 1,$$ thus $X$ is your usual exponential distribution with mean $\beta$.

The takeaway here is that the specification of any probability distribution is **incomplete** without explicitly stating its support.  You can write any density or mass function you like, but if you do not state the support, your distribution is meaningless.

Comment: $f(x) = \alpha/\beta\, e^{-x/\beta}+c$ is the density. It's a generalized exponential distribution. curve_fit() is basic a parameter estimation. Because the result of c=3.18496892e-06 is nearly 0, so to find E(x), it's set to 0.

Comment: @milowang You don't seem to have understood my response.  Merely fitting a curve to a set of data does not mean that the curve you have fit is a probability distribution.  And if you don't have a proper probability density, attempting to calculate an expectation is **meaningless**.  Your comment is indicative of an insufficient knowledge of basic probability theory; additionally, your failure to specify a support for the random variable you are modeling means your question **cannot** be answered.

Comment: The PDF is specified in terms of $\alpha$,  $\beta$, c, and x.  $f(x) = \alpha/\beta\, e^{-x/\beta}+c (x>0)$.   The density f(x) is 0 for x less than or equal to 0.

Comment: I think there's some "goes without saying" thing that the script didn't  say. But the script did calculate the expected value as: $\alpha*\beta+1/\beta$ in [here](https://discourse-cdn.global.ssl.fastly.net/udacity/uploads/default/original/3X/b/3/b3c154ca0cd23a0400f6ead5a5b9ec0791e81108.png)

Comment: @milowang As I have explained, if the support is $X \in (0,\infty)$, then the only value of $c$ for which the function $f$ is a PDF is $c = 0$; and if $c = 0$, then you are also forced to have $\alpha = 1$.  If you obtain some other fit such as what you describe, then the following two statements cannot simultaneously hold:  (a) the support is $x \in (0,\infty)$; (b) $f_X(x)$ is a PDF.

Comment: @milowang As for "goes without saying," that would be the case if your random variable followed some well-known probability distribution.  But because the form of the density that you have chosen to fit is **not** standard and does **not** integrate to $1$ on $(0,\infty)$ for general values of $\alpha, \beta, c$, then it is **not reasonable** to expect that $X > 0$ can be assumed.

Comment: The PDF of Exponential distribution is  $f(x) = 1/\beta\, e^{-x/\beta}$. What the  script did is add two new parameters $\alpha$ and c to do a little change.

Comment: I don't know if you have read the [script](https://discourse-cdn.global.ssl.fastly.net/udacity/uploads/default/original/3X/b/3/b3c154ca0cd23a0400f6ead5a5b9ec0791e81108.png). It do find parameters for a and c using curve_fit() which is a  implement of Maximum likelihood estimation

Comment: @milowang You do not understand basic probability theory, let alone the concept of parameter estimation, and you don't seem to be able to accept that what I have told you is **mathematical fact**.  You cannot just arbitrarily "add parameters" and run some computer program to do "maximum likelihood estimation" on those parameters.  You have **no** idea what you are talking about and it is clear that you do not want to understand; therefore, I am voting to close your question.

Comment: What I want to argue is that if what you said is true, the curve_fit function in spicy should not return a estimation. It should raise a similar error like what you've complained about. And since this PDF is given by a online [course](https://discourse-cdn.global.ssl.fastly.net/udacity/uploads/default/original/3X/c/c/cc3fd5b0014e4f04813c317684a86346d0222c60.png), I simply want to believe that the programmer of curve_fit function and course designer are not as stupid as you assume I was

Comment: @milowang You can fit data to almost **any** family of functions by least squares, but not all such functions are probability densities.  You can fit data to a general quadratic, e.g. determine parameters $\beta_k$ such that $y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i + \beta_2 x_i^2$ minimizes the sum of squared differences but that doesn't make it a **probability density**.

Comment: It's obvious that I cannot convince you that the calculation you are claiming to be true is in fact complete nonsense.  Feel free to ask elsewhere, e.g., in the mathematics stack exchange site, and you will see how quickly other people will tell you exactly what I have told you.

Comment: Then what does the $E(t) = \alpha*\beta+1/\beta = 153.83 secs$ stands for?